# RegularExpressions Extract All Decimal Values and Iterate Through

Tags: c#, regex

Say I had the String

```
<Records>
         <record id='818591'/>
         <record id='818592'/>
         <record id='818593'/>
         <record id='818594'/>
         <record id='818595'/>
         <record id='818596'/>
         <record id='818597'/>
         <record id='818598'/>
</Records>
```

How, in C#, could I extract, and iterate through every "id" value.

I'm assuming it will be something like this:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(archerResponse,@"<Records>(<record id='\d*'/>)*</Records>"))
{
       //get value
}
```

But how do I just pull out the decimal?

Comment: Let's pretend it's invalid xml

Comment: If your xml is invalid the parser would throw, which is desired, because you would want to know if your data source is bad (garbage in / garbage out). But if you expect it to be invalid regex would be a good alternative.

Comment: A Decimal is a particular sort of number in .NET - your example shows only integers. Do you need to parse decimals with region-specific digit grouping and decimal mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an XML parser:

```
XElement.Parse(archerResponse)
    .Elements("record")
    .SelectMany(n => n.Attributes("id"))
    .Select(x => x.Value); //gives you a collection of the items needed.
```

If you really want regex, use capturing groups:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(archerResponse,@"<Records>(<record id='(\d+)'/>)*</Records>"))
{
    string result = match.Groups[0];
}
```

(note the brackets around the `\d+`!)

Answer (score 1):

```
// main program
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Records> <record id='818591'/> <record id='818592'/> <record id='818593'/> <record id='818594'/> <record id='818595'/> <record id='818596'/> <record id='818597'/> <record id='818598'/></Records>");

            foreach (string s in doc.Descendants().Attributes("id").Select(a => a.Value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

or if you're dead set on using regex...  the following is a regex that you can use.

```
"id='(.*?)'"
```

http://rubular.com/r/Pd4NbqDeVw

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance than you can use `XDocument.Parse(string)` instead of `XDocument.Load()`

Comment: No, you would use XElement.Parse ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this on for size:

```
    string text =
        @"<Records><record id='818591'/><record id='818592'/><record id='818593'/><record id='818594'/><record id='818595'/><record id='818596'/><record id='818597'/><record id='818598'/></Records>";

    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?");

    if(matches.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var value in matches)
        {
            Console.Write(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this regex pattern allows for optional decimal precision, ie matches 1 and 1.01